# DELL R730XD 256GB memory but just showed 251GB on linux with command `free -h` and `htop` , why?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware, htop, free

A DELL R730XD server with 32GiB * 8, totaling 256GB of memory, is correctly recognized as 256GB in the BIOS. When checking the memory information using "dmidecode -t memory" in Linux, the total of 256GB is also reported correctly. However, the "free -h" command consistently shows a total of 251GB on both CentOS and Arch Linux. same for "htop" command. Why?
[image]

Some told me that's cause the different between GB and GiB, It's wrong, 256GB != 251GiB.

there some information about:

memory info on bios/iDRAC
[image]

memory info on windows server 2019
[image]

Comment: Please refrain from posting text as images.

Comment: I can't got the text output on first photo. There is no ssh on.